# Passing Json from action method in Asp.net MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am fetching the last five added products like following :-

```
var products = pe.Products.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).Take(5);
```

Now, I want to pass the above data as a Json in the following format :-

`[{"content": "<div class='slide_inner'><a class=' continues... ","content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src=' coninues... "
}]`

Comment: on a side note, I think you're miss-using JSON here. By definition JSON is to allow exchange of data between server and client in a lightweight way in an object notation. Normally you wouldn't put HTML into your C# entity would you? Why going with JSON here?

Comment: @torm ya i realized that....Now, i am using the child action and passing them directly. Thanks for pointing and explaining out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `Controller`, you can return a [JsonResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult.aspx) as the result of your action:

```
return Json(products)
```

Behind the scene, your `Product`collection will be serialized in a json string by the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx).

Comment: I have an ActionResult method which returns Json("string"). This one simple passes *string* with no braces or brackets, why so ??

Comment: Because that's how a string is serialized into `json`. Use an anonymous object if you want to get an object as the output: `Json(new { "aaa"});`